# Difference between ChartModule & HighchartsChartModule in Angular-HighCharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts

Can anyone please help on the difference between using **ChartModule** & **HighchartsChartModule** in the angular application. I am a bit of confusion in few angular highchart related technical docs they preferring use **ChartModule**

```
import { ChartModule} from 'highcharts-angular';
```

and in some documents, I am seeing using of **HighchartsChartModule** .

```
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
```

I am suspecting here it may be angular cli version base we have to decide which we have to be used please teach me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you read 2 different docs the official [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular) and [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) and another one [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts). Anyway as long as you use the same module name you can call it as you like `import { VenkiChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';` will works too.

Comment: @Core972 Thanks for the reply, So, I can use any name with `ChartModule` from `highcharts-angular` package kind of thing? So no matter which name we are using to import `ChartModule`  from `highcharts-angular`?

Comment: Yes the name is only a reference used by the app.

Comment: Tried with sample example but getting this error  `ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/vyepuri/Documents/My_Angular/AngularHighCharts/Angular6WithHighCharts/node_modules/highcharts-angular/highcharts-angular"' has no exported member 'VenkiChartModule'`

Comment: but when using name suggetsed in documnet like `HighchartsChartModule` then not getting error & page rendering properly.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in online code editor like codesandbox?

Comment: Hi @WojciechChmiel,  I am follwing this doc `https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular#installing` to create simple pie-chart  using angular highcharts. Here I notice `import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';` and in some other doc I notice `import { ChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';` So, I want know the difference between these two imports ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two Angular wrappers for Highcharts:

1. ***highcharts-angular*** official Highcharts wrapper: 
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular 
   It uses **HighchartsChartModule**: 
   `import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';`
2. ***angular-highcharts***: 
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts
   It uses **ChartModule**: 
   `import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';`

Comment: Thank you Wojciech Chmiel. looks `angular-highcharts` will be use with angular 7 version or more than 7 version but looks can't campatiable with below angular 7 versions & `highcharts-angular` will be campatiable with angular 6+. And looks in my working applicaion we are uisng angular 6.1.0 version. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can use `angular-highcharts` with Angular version lower than 7 check here: https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts/blob/master/README.md#angular5--angular6-support. And `highcharts-angular` should be compatible with 6.1.0 version.

Comment: I hope we can use `angular-highcharts` even in 7 or above angular versions Wojciech Chmiel. Please have a look here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nkrgd?file=package.json](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nkrgd?file=package.json)